# Error in migrating sharing rule

Tags: migration

I got a sharing rule which is criteria based sharing rule 
on custom object
and it says
if

Product Name  equals ''

Share with All Partner users

Readonly
This rule works in terms of sharing the records.But when i try to migrate it using change sets (Just this sharing rule) It gives me

> An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you
>   contact support: 1748658427-9347 (1893024205)

Does anyone know why?
Is it because i put '' ? and it takes it as empty value or something?

Answer (score 1):

This is an internal SF error, so I'm afraid the only way to diagnose it is to open a ticket with SF.  Give them that number and they can check there error logs.

Comment: But is it normal to put '' when we have a sharing rule to check for fields empty condition.or is there a better option?

Comment: Did you actually put in '', or do you just leave it blank?

Comment: i put '' and save it. and it looks it is blank.because if open it again and simply press save it says 'field empty'..is it not same for you as well?/ or whats the correct way to do it..because when i replaced '' by abcd ,,migration is validated successfully.so i guess error lies there

Comment: Take out the '', and just leave it blank and then save it

Comment: it will give an error, Error: Empty value   ,,if i leave it blank

Comment: Yea I really don't know then, I would open a ticket with SF.  I'd welcome anyone to correct me as I havent actually created sharing rules off blank values before

Comment: were you able to find a way to create sharing rules with blank values? We ran into the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: i could create the sharing rule by putting in ''..but as i raised ,you cannot migrate it.so..what i did was manually updated the sharing rule in production